# product details page is featured attribute yes show attribute in magento 2.4

Tags: attributes, magento2.4

This attribute only show Is Featured Yes for attribute in product details page in magento 2.4

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

```
<?php
  $_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
  $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<ul class="mb">
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText("test")): ?>
    <li>
        <span class="primary-c"><?= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("test")->getStoreLabel() ?>:&nbsp;</span>
        <span><?= $_product->getAttributeText("test") ?></span>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement to show some text attribute values on the frontend on the product view page after the short description.

I have modified `catalog_product_view.xml` and added my own template file in my custom theme.

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.measurements" template="product/view/customattribute.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMeasurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="measurements"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customattribute.phtml**

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue) { ?>
    <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I did it using a custom theme, the same can be achieved using the module as well.